# Can you change the default inheritance of classes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, metaprogramming

As a little hobby project, I'm trying to build up my own object system. I was wondering if there is a way of changing the default inheritance of all classes from `Object` to my base class `Entity`, so that whenever I create a new class I don't have to explicitly say `class Thing < Entity`; ideally, I would just be able to say `class Thing` and have its default superclass be my `Entity` class.

Comment: I don't see any point in doing this. Whatever feature you are planning to have on `Entity` could be implemented on `Object` or `include`/`extend`ed to `Object`, and your're done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you could do this by modifying the [relevant part of the Ruby source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_195/class.c#L456) and recompiling Ruby:

```c
VALUE
rb_define_class_id(ID id, VALUE super)
{
    VALUE klass;

    if (!super) super = rb_cObject;  // <-- where the default is set
    klass = rb_class_new(super);
    // ...
```

But that’s a huge hassle and requires patching and running a custom Ruby and probably has a lot of gotchas and things that are hard-coded to assume `Object` is the default.

And, on top of that, what’s the point? If you replace `Object` with something else as the default superclass, every class—including those in Ruby core—will now inherit from this new default superclass. You could get the same effect (just without the different name) far more easily and without needing a custom Ruby *by just changing `Object` itself*. That’s the beauty of being able to reopen classes! For example:

```
class Object
  def foo
    'bar!'
  end
end

class A; end

A.new.foo  #=> 'bar!'
```

If you wanted to be kind you might even just put all the relevant methods in an `Entity` module instead of a class and then `include` it into `Object`.

Comment: +1, though you might show how to monkeypatch Object, or include a module in it. (You may even be adding this edit as I type.)

Comment: +1, Thanks for the input! I've begun using Ruby only recently and though I'm starting to become quite familiar with its syntax, I'm still not fully accustomed to the idea of an essentially open-source programming language. And since I haven't been using it long, I haven't really been able to experience the power of dynamically modifying classes. I believe I may go with your last suggestion.

Comment: @DesAdams It’s powerful, but I’d advise using it sparingly with core Ruby classes, as it can get out of hand all to easily.

Comment: +1 for "I’d advise using it sparingly with core Ruby classes".

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately this is not possible in Ruby. Ruby does not have a Meta-Object Protocol like e.g. CLOS that would allow you to manipulate the core semantics of the Object Model. It would be nice, though!